# Setting State and performing new Searches in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-thunk

I've got this React app, its being compiled by babel and bundled by webpack.

in a timetable page `TimetableManagePage.js` I have this snippet:

```
nextWeek() {
    this.setState({
        today: this.state.today.clone().add(1, 'w')
    });

    this.searchSessions();
}

previousWeek() {
    this.setState({
        today: this.state.today.clone().subtract(1, 'w')
    });

    this.searchSessions();
}

searchSessions() {
    this.props.actions.searchSessions({
            query: {
                range: {
                    when: {
                        gte: this.state.today.clone().startOf('week').toISOString(),
                        lte: this.state.today.clone().endOf('week').toISOString()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .then(() => this.setState({loading: false}))
        .catch(() => this.setState({loading: false}));
}
```

The idea is, if someone clicks the arrows on this:
[image: screenshot]

It will move to the next or previous week.

The `searchSessions` runs off the state of `today`, which the `previousWeek` and `nextWeek` update. However, I'm finding that the state isn't updated when the search is ran.

`this.props.actions.searchSessions` update a redux store state, so will set new props on the component...

Now, I thought that maybe this search actually belongs in the `render` function, all state should be changed by then... however, any state change in the component will cause the `render` to be re-run, which means there could be loads of calls to the search, more than there should be.

What is the best way to perform the new search when only the today state is updated? Should I be looking at [`componentWillUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate)

Answer (score 0):

You should add shouldComponentUpdate(nextState) function and should compare

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextState){  
 if(nextState.today != this.state.today) 
   return true;
}
```

then it will only update your page when today state is updated. After that you can call it from componentWillUpdate or whereever you want.

```
componentWillUpdate(nextState){
  if(nextState.today!=this.state.today){
     doIt();
   }
}
```

Comment: but `today` isn't the only state on the component, there is `isSaving`, `showModal`, `loading`....

Comment: there you will add your code into componentWillUpdate(nextState) and the same thing again if (state.today is changed) do something..  to it I only added that to run it only once.

Comment: I'm using the `componentDidUpdate`, that way all state change is executed on, but after it is finished, I then check if `today` changed and run the search accordingly